# Highlight Full Duplicate Rows (Not Individual Values)

Tags: excel, vba

I have looked at several other stack overflow questions, however I haven't found the answer I am looking for.

I have an excel sheet with 25000 rows in the following format:

```
userid  |  taskid  |  taskcode
 1      |     3    |     K
 1      |     4    |     O
 1      |     4    |     L
 1      |     5    |     O
 2      |     3    |     O
```

What I want to do is identify any rows that are duplicated considering `userid` and `taskid`, in the above example I would expect the second and third rows to be highlighted.

I'm not sure how feasible it is, I'd ideally like to identify the duplicate row containing the `taskcode` `O` rather than `L`.

My end goal is to remove all duplicate userid / taskid rows with the taskcode O regardless of how it is achieved (highlighting then sorting by highlights or using vba).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok solved it after messing around - I'll leave this answer here for future reference unless there is a more efficient way identified.

**Step 1**

Create a combined cell with both `userid` and `taskid` values using `=A2&B2` in column D.

**Step 2**

Use the built in condition formatting for highlighting duplicates.

**Step 3**

Custom sort using the highlighted duplicate red highlighted cells at the top, then sorting the `taskcode` in the custom order selected (O, K, L)

**Step 4**

Simply highlight all the rows (which are now in blocks) that you wish to delete.

Comment: +1 I would have used the concatenated approach also, nice and simple

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna try using VBA.

```
Sub duplicates_separation()



      Dim duplicate(), i As Long
        Dim delrange As Range, cell As Long
        Dim delrange2 As Range
        Dim shtIn As Worksheet
        Dim numofrows1


          Set shtIn = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")

        x = 2
        y = 1

        Set delrange = shtIn.Range("c1:b30000")  'set your range here
       Set delrange2 = shtIn.Range("b1:f30000")
       ReDim duplicate(0)
    'search duplicates in 2nd column
        For cell = 1 To delrange.Cells.Count
            If Application.CountIf(delrange, delrange(cell)) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve duplicate(i)
                duplicate(i) = delrange(cell).Address
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next
    'search duplicates in 3rd column
        For cell = 1 To delrange2.Cells.Count
            If Application.CountIf(delrange2, delrange2(cell)) > 1 Then
                ReDim Preserve duplicate(i)
                duplicate(i) = delrange2(cell).Address
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next


            'print duplicates

        For i = UBound(duplicate) To LBound(duplicate) Step -1
        shtIn.Range(duplicate(i)).EntireRow.Value.delete
        x = x + 1
    Next i


    End Sub
```

Comment: Above code did not work for me. It freezes for a minute and finally gives "Object Required" warning box without highlighting any duplications.